# Can I increase randomness by changing my algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

Here is a generator that I'm currently using:

```
from random import Random

def shuffle(size):
    """Yield random items from range(size) without replacement."""
    pool = list(range(size))
    rng = Random()
    while pool:
        yield pool.pop(rng.randrange(len(pool)))
```

As I use this generator, it seems less random than it could be. For example, the first 4 items often all end up in either the first or second half of the result.

I'm considering making this change:

```
def shuffle(size):
    """Yield random items from range(size) without replacement."""
    pool = list(range(size))
    rng = Random()
    while pool:
        i = rng.randrange(len(pool))
        yield pool[i]
        pool[i] = pool[-1]
        del pool[-1]
```

This is similar to something [random.sample](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py) (line 326) does. I don't know if this is for speed or because it makes it more random without sacrificing speed.

I prefer the first example for simplicity, but the second one mixes things up a bit more, and I don't know if PRNGs are up to par with true randomness. Is there a way to prove whether or not the second example would be more random, perhaps by citing weaknesses in the Mersenne Twister algorithm (which Python uses)?

If it's not possible to prove anything one way or the other, how would I test both algorithms for randomness? I know I need to write a test with many trials, but I have no idea how to analyze the results.

I don't want to use `random.sample`, because I want my final list to be partially sorted, and I think a generator is better for that.

Comment: "For example, the first 4 items often all end up in either the first or second half of the result" - that's completely normal.

Comment: First version is fine. Your second version does nothing but waste time. No, there is no possibility that anything you do will improve on straightforward use of MT, and every likelihood you will make it worse. Don't roll you own crypto, and don't roll your own RNG unless you're a serious math geek.

Comment: Edited to clarify why I'm considering the second version. I'm not trying to roll my own RNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.py`'s private `_randbelow()` is what supplies uniformity when making a pseudo-random choice from N possibilities.  Everything from `randrange()` through `shuffle()` *builds* on that.  There's nothing you can do to improve on it short of replacing the Twister with a better underlying base PRNG.

`sample()` is coded as it is for speed, not to "improve randomness".  Popping from "the middle" of a list (as your first method does) takes `O(len(pool))` time on average, so your first method takes time quadratic in `size` if run to exhaustion.  Popping from the right end of a list takes constant time, so your second method has much better `O(size)` asymptotic time behavior if run to exhaustion.  Python's `sample()` doesn't pop at all, because it's not a *necessary* expense to solve the problem.

But note that the asymptotics don't really matter unless the list is quite long.  If, say, `size` is less than a few hundred, you may not notice any practical difference in speed between your two methods.  But you will if `size` can, e.g., be millions.

I don't know what "I don't want to use `random.sample`, because I want my final list to be partially sorted" could possibly mean.  There is no "final list" in anything you showed, and *any* method that picks elements at random without replacement will yield "partially sorted" results purely by chance.

Here's one reasonably approachable way to quantify whether a shuffling method "seems random":

http://gregbee.ch/blog/determining-the-bias-of-a-shuffle-algorithm

That (or any other workable approach) computes statistics based on many thousands of trial runs.

Comment: When I used `random.sample`, I had to re-sort the sections of the list that I needed sorted. Using a generator lets me insert items with `bisect.insort` when I'm in a section that I want sorted. I only mentioned it because I'm sure people would've asked "Why don't you just use `random.sample`?" It's not actually relevent to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a list of `list(range(10))` and you're tracking when the number `5` gets returned.

In a random scenario, if the algorithm were run 100 times, the number `5` would get returned as the first number equally as the last number. Thus, if you keep track of a map of returned position by frequency you would hopefully see something like:

```
[{0: 10, 1: 11, 
2: 8, 3: 12, 
4: 10, 5: 10, 
6: 9, 7: 10, 
8: 10, 9: 10]
```

You might be able to use something like a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to show that the distributions are different or the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick test:

```
- Chi-square distribution
- Incomplete gamma function
- Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

If you're not intimately familiar with all of these mathematical concepts, don't mess with RNGs. Nothing you do to "mix up" Python's built-in MT will make it better, and there are thousands of ways to make it worse. The tools provided are very good. Keep it simple, follow the rules.